# App cannot be launched, but seems to have installed

Tags: android, android-manifest

I changed the manifest of my app, and now the app cannot be launched. No icon. However, when I check installed under setting Application Manager, I see it there!
Whats going on???  I have used same permissions before. I just changed which app was MAIN and launcher. Now cannot see the app. Does not come up via Studio or show up in Apps device!!!!

Update: created new app with same permissions and launches ok, so it does not really seem to be permissions ...

```
 Installing com.mycomp.myapp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mycomp.myapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.myapp.
Success
  09-21 13:40:43.261      454-499/? W/PackageManager﹕ verifying app can be  installed or not
  09-21 13:40:49.171      454-499/? W/PackageManager﹕ Unknown permission android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATE in package com.mycomp.myapp
  09-21 13:40:49.171      454-499/? W/PackageManager﹕ Not granting permission  android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS to package com.mycomp.myapp     (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x18be46)





 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycomp.myapp.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.CheckValuesSercice"
        android:exported="false" />
        <service`enter code here`
            android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.TestService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.ValuesService"
        android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.Guest"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.SetUsageAccessToApp"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.AddItems"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
       android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.TestValues"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.Login"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.HomeScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.Listings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.Authorizing"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.ThemeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.EditHelpMessage"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.Test"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.mycomp.myapp.test.ForOther"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
       </activity>
       </application>

    </manifest>
```

Here is log

```
 Uploading file
local path: C:\projects\MyProj\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mycomp.myapp
Installing com.mycomp.myapp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mycomp.myapp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.mycomp.myapp
Success
```

So now I can see it under Setting ->Application Manager.  But not under Apps on the device.

Comment: Put your manifest file here.. let us see what is the problem

Comment: Revert all the changes in the manifest file and see if it works.

Comment: You have not given the specified permissions in the manifest.  That is the issue, I guess.

Comment: The problem has to do for sure with `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` settings in the manifest, please show your manifest so we can check.

Comment: changed the manifest of my app?? what changes were these?? anyway you are probably seeing the old application in the Application Manager not the new one. There's usually a 2nd page of apps, so maybe its there, use the mouse to slide to 2nd page.

Comment: Did you unintsall the old one before installing the new one? If you've changed the config for the MAIN/LAUNCHER Activity, you need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: I guarantee the app cannot be seen from list of 'Apps'  but I can see it under Application Manager in Settings at 10MB.  Not sure whats happening!

Comment: yes, uninstall and reinstall several times. I have added the manifest

Comment: 2:08:08 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
2:09:38 PM Gradle build finished with 1 warnings(s) in 1m 30s 738ms
2:09:44 PM Session 'app': running

Comment: You miss this attribute: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in your **SplashScreen** Activity. I also set mine as MAIN, leaving the Main Activity only as DEFAULT.

Comment: @MuayThai in your manifest you define your package name as `com.mycomp.myapp.knock` but in logs it prints `com.mycomp.myapp`.. try to change it as `com.mycomp.myapp`.. and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

All your activities seem to be in the *test* directory of your project. Please check in your IDE if it does not recognise this directory as a default directory for tests (would be highlighted in green on the Project view), as it would mean that the classes will NOT be compiled into the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you delete app from device properly: go to Settings -> Applications. If you find your app here then choose it and make "delete for all users" in setting menu. After that try to inslall your app again.